# Spark: Task not serializable (Broadcast/RDD/SparkContext)

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

There are numerous questions about `Task is not serializable` in Spark. However, this case seems quite particular.

I have created a class:

```
class Neighbours(e: RDD[E], m: KMeansModel) extends Serializable {
  val allEs: RDD[(String, E)] = e.map(e => (e.w, e))
    .persist()
  val sc = allEs.sparkContext
  val centroids = sc.broadcast(m.clusterCenters)
  [...]
```

The class defines the following method:

```
private def centroidDistances(v: Vector): Array[Double] = {
  centroids.value.map(c => (centroids.value.indexOf(c), Vectors.sqdist(v, c)))
    .sortBy(_._1)
    .map(_._2)
}
```

However, when the class is called, a `Task is not serializable` exception is thrown.

Strange enough, a tiny change in the header of class `Neighbours` suffices to fix the issue. Instead of creating a `val sc: SparkContext` to use for broadcasting, I merely inline the code that creates the Spark context:

```
class Neighbours(e: RDD[E], m: KMeansModel) extends Serializable {
  val allEs: RDD[(String, E)] = e.map(e => (e.w, e))
  .setName("embeddings")
  .persist()
  val centroids = allEmbeddings.sparkContext(m.clusterCenters)
  [...]
```

My question is: how does the second variant make a difference? What goes wrong in the first one? Intuitively, this should be merely syntactic sugar, is this a bug in Spark?

I use Spark 1.4.1 on a Hadoop/Yarn cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define

```
class Neighbours(e: RDD[E], m: KMeansModel) extends Serializable {
  ...
  val sc = allEmbeddings.sparkContext
  val centroids = sc.broadcast(m.clusterCenters)
  ...
}
```

You have made `sc` into a class variable, meaning it could be accessed from an instance of `Neighbours` e.g. `neighbours.sc`. This means that `sc` needs to be serializable, which is it not.

When you inline the code, only the final value of `centroids` needs to be serializable. `centroids` is of type `Broadcast` which is Serializable.

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on this. I was assuming that `sc` would become serializable because it is a class variable. Is there a way to define `sc` so that it actually is serializable?

Comment: I'm not aware of a method to change the serializability of a provided clas, but also I'm not sure that passing your spark context around is a valid thing to do in Spark anyway. Since you can get to it anyway from your RDD, do you have a need to serializable the context?

Comment: Actually not. This comment was merely about concise code; in case the SparkContext is used in other places, storing it once in a variable seems cleaner than retrieving it again from an RDD. However, you are probably right that passing `sc` as a variable to begin with would be a better option (if that is what you meant).

Comment: if you want to be able to use `sc` concisely in code, you could define it as a `def` pointing to `allEmbeddings.sparkContext` rather than a `val`? I'd expect that not to cause any serialization issues.